# my php script for contact form is not working

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

Hello I have wrote the following code, for a contact us form for my website which I am creating with joomla. The form gets displayed in the website [website link](http://masihiatchist.com/index.php/contact-us) but I have two issues
1. The "message part" the title of it falls at the bottom of the textarea box and not at the top
2. i am not a pro coder, specially in PHP. when I type and press submit nothing happens. I assume my php doesn't work.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">



            <label for="name">اسم</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/> <br>


            <label for="email">ایمیل</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" /><br>


            <label for="message">پیام</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="20" row="50" ></textarea> <br>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />



</form>

<style type="text/css">

form
{
display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
font-family: "arial";
border:2px solid gray;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 900px;
height: 550px;

background: #580000;}

input
{
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
}

textarea
{
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
resize: none;
width: 200px;
height: 250px;

background: #fff;


}

#submit {
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius:6px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: poiner;
     border:none;
}



#submit:hover {
    border: none;
    background:grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #777;
}
</style>


<?php
$ToEmail = 'evelina@jfaproduction.com';
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form';
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".nl2br($_POST["message"])."";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
?>
```

Comment: Please refer to the Joomla Documentation. Not trying to bring you down, but you have done this all wrong. There are coding standards and particular methods that one should adhere to with Joomla. If you're not an experienced coder, then have a look for contact forms on the Joomla Extensions Directory as there are dozens ;)

Comment: i tried it and it's working.

Comment: when you press submit it shows that its submitted but I don't receive any emails.
I know I am not a good coder, but I've used a extension called sourcer which allows you to type html, css, php and JavaScript in your article and publish it. that is what I did and it displays correctly. all i need is for my php to work

Comment: are you running it in you local enveironment? maybe it's because or any SMTP setting of your web server... because i tried it on my own server and the email has been sent.

Comment: its not local, I am running this on the Rackspace server

Comment: @codeeeeeNOT - Do you not think it would be easier to use a contact module from the Joomla Extensions Directory, assign a custom position to it and import that position in your article (which doesn't even require Sourcerer) ?

Comment: and using if($_POST){

Comment: I am ok to use something like that if I can find one that is nice and looks good. all the ones I found are very simple and small and I cant change anything

Comment: Why don't you just use he core contact form for that matter? You don't seem to be doing anything that it doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mockup using Joomla coding standards. I'm only showing you this way as you seem quite keen to stick to using Sourcerer.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post">
      <label for="name">اسم</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/> <br>

      <label for="email">ایمیل</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" /><br>

      <label for="message">پیام</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="20" row="50" ></textarea> <br>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
   $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
   $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
   $post = $input->post;  
   $submit = $post->get('submit');

   if(isset($submit) {

       $mailer->setSender($post->get('email'));
       $mailer->addRecipient('evelina@jfaproduction.com');

       $body = 'Name: ' . $post->get('name');
       $body .= 'Email: ' . $post->get('email');
       $body .= 'Message: ' . $post->get('message');

       $mailer->setSubject('Site contact form');
       $mailer->setBody($body);

       $send = $mailer->Send();
       if ( $send !== true ) {
           echo 'Error sending email';
       } 
       else {
           echo 'Success!';
       }

   }

?>
```